# Unable to constrain generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections, constraints

I can't figure out what's happening here. I'm building a wrapper for a Dictionary collection. The idea is that, when the size of the collection is small, it will use a normal in-memory Dictionary; but, when a threshold number of items is reached, it will internally switch to an on-disk Dictionary (I'm using the ManagedEsent PersistentDictionary class).

A snippet of the on-disk version is below. When compiling, it fails with the following error:

> "The type 'T_KEY' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.Isam.Esent.Collections.Generic.PersistentDictionary<TKey,TValue>'.
>   There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from
>   'T_KEY' to 'System.IComparable<T_KEY>'."

So I modified the class definition to be:

```
class DiskDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE> : IHybridDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE>
    where T_KEY : System.IComparable
```

thinking that would do the trick, but it didn't. I tried constraining the definition IHybridDictionary too but that didn't have any effect. Any thoughts on what's going on?

Original definition of DiskDictionary:

```
class DiskDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE> : IHybridDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE>
{
    string dir;
    PersistentDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE> d;

    public DiskDictionary(string dir)
    {
        this.dir = dir;
        //d = new PersistentDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE>(dir);
    }

    ... some other methods...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DiskDictionary` class need to specify that `T_KEY` implements `IComparable<TKey>` :

```
class DiskDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE> : IHybridDictionary<T_KEY, T_VALUE>
    where T_KEY : System.IComparable<T_KEY>
{
}
```

There is both a generic and a non generic version of this interface and you were specifying the wrong one.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much. I had originally tried that and it didn't work, but I hadn't propogated it through the other class definitions.